# Mobile Page not showing up - Joomla

Tags: css, joomla

Hi I am looking for some help in regards to understanding why the following page does not show up on a mobile size screen (480px) as all the other pages that have been built show up fine.

http://leicesterbakery.co.uk/index.php/product

I have a module class suffix with the following styles within the media queries in order to control what is shown on a mobile and what is shown a desktop.

```
(media query with max-width: 480px)
.range_full {
    display: none;
}

.range_resp {
    display: block;
}

Normal CSS file
.range_full {
    display: block;
}

.range_resp {
    display: none;
}
```

Would appreciate it if somebody could advise as really cant work out this isnt showing up.

Comment: I can't find `range_resp` being used on that page, is it added by JS?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `display: none` on `.range_full`

Change it to block and it will show:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

/***** BASIC LAYOUT *****/

.range_full {
    display: block;
}

.range_resp {
    display:block;
}

.fullrange_full {
    display:none;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks davw, that does work the weird thing is if you select this page, http://leicesterbakery.co.uk/index.php/product/pitta-bread I have added the range_resp as the full screen .range_full is set to null but then the mobile version should use the range_resp, works on all pages bar this one

Comment: @user3191160 if my answer helped, please do mark it as correct,